# Getting count from inner join table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, subquery, inner-join

I have tables as described below:

*subscription_plans* (Table for storing all plans)

```
id   plan   days_limit  added_on  status   rate
------------------------------------------------
1    PlanA     15       1398249706  1      150.00
2    PlanB     15       1398249706  1      150.00
```

*subscribed_videos* (Table for storing details of video in each plans)

```
id   plan_id   videoid
----------------------
1      1        1
2      2        2
```

*subscription_groups* (Table for storing groups where a plan can be part of another plan. ie, Plan A be a plan with 2 other individual plans, Plan B and C )

```
id   plan_id   assosiated_plan_id   added_on
----------------------------------------------
1      1         2                  1398249706
```

*usersubscription* (Table for storing user subscribed plans)

```
id    user_id   plan_id  subscribed_on
---------------------------------------
1     1         1        1398771106
```

Now, my problem is that how can I get the count of videos for each plans. If Plan A contains both Plan B and C (*subscription_groups* table), then the count should return the total video count for each individual plans in that particular plan. Now I have done with a query which will return plan details along with count of videos for a plan but I am not able to join it with *subscription_groups*. How can I accomplish this in a single query.

```
 $data['planquery']=$this->db->query("select 
 us.plan_id,us.subscribed_on,sp.plan,sp.days_limit,sp.rate,count(sv.videoid) from
 usersubscription as us INNER JOIN
 subscription_plans as sp ON us.plan_id=sp.id INNER JOIN subscribed_videos as sv ON       sp.id=sv.plan_id where sp.status=1 and us.user_id=1");
```

Expected Result:

```
plan_id subscribed_on  plan  days_limit  rate   count
-------------------------------------------------------
1       1398771106     PlanA  15         150.00  2
```

Can anyone help me to find a solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add a bit more sample data set with your expected result set ?

Comment: Well, group association part is not that clear, did you mean PlanA contains the same set of videos as PlanB and PlanC?

Comment: @avisheks..Plan association means, a plan may contain other plans ie, if there are 3 plans, say A,B,C, A can be a plan which is a superset of B and C. ie, if I am subscribed to plan A, then I will be able to view videos of Plan B and C.

Comment: @jenz consider providing a properly representative data set (see sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET -- and note that the `id` column in most of your tables appears to serve no purpose!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so

```
SELECT 
  us.plan_id,
  us.subscribed_on,
  sp.plan,
  sp.days_limit,
  sp.rate,
  COUNT(sv.videoid) 
FROM
  usersubscription AS us 
  RIGHT JOIN subscription_plans AS sp 
    ON us.plan_id = sp.id 
  INNER JOIN subscribed_videos AS sv 
    ON sp.id = sv.plan_id 
  INNER JOIN subscription_groups g
    ON(g.plan_id =sv .plan_id OR sv.plan_id= g.assosiated_plan_id)
 WHERE sp.status = 1 
 AND (us.user_id = 1 OR us.user_id IS NULL )
```

### [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/98fa0/12)

Since user has only plan associated but the associated plan can also has another plan linked so the last condition will check the user id but for is null to for the second linked plan user id will be null due to right join on  `subscription_plans`

**Edit**

```
SELECT 
u.plan_id,
u.subscribed_on,
p.plan,
  p.days_limit,
  p.rate
,COUNT(DISTINCT v.`videoid`) 
 FROM `usersubscription` u
JOIN `subscription_groups` g 
ON (u.`plan_id` = g.`plan_id`)
RIGHT JOIN `subscription_plans` p 
ON(u.`plan_id` = p.`id` OR g.`assosiated_plan_id` = p.`id`)
INNER JOIN `subscribed_videos` v  ON(v.`plan_id`=g.`assosiated_plan_id` OR u.`plan_id`= v.`plan_id`)
WHERE u.`id`=1 AND p.`status` = 1
```

### [Demo 1](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/98fa0/13) [Demo2](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/72a68e/2)

For video ids you can use group_concat

```
SELECT 
u.plan_id,
u.subscribed_on,
p.plan,
  p.days_limit,
  p.rate
,COUNT(DISTINCT v.`videoid`) `video_count` ,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT v.`videoid`) `video_ids`
 FROM `usersubscription` u
JOIN `subscription_groups` g 
ON (u.`plan_id` = g.`plan_id`)
RIGHT JOIN `subscription_plans` p 
ON(u.`plan_id` = p.`id` OR g.`assosiated_plan_id` = p.`id`)
INNER JOIN `subscribed_videos` v  ON(v.`plan_id`=g.`assosiated_plan_id` OR u.`plan_id`= v.`plan_id`)
WHERE u.`id`=1 AND p.`status` = 1
```

### [Demo 1a](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/98fa0/14) [Demo 2a](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/72a68e/3)

Comment: @Khalid..It is not giving me proper record when I executed in my project. I will share my complete table details.

Comment: Please check http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/72a68e/1.. It is showing Plan B instead of Plan A also the count is not correct. It is also showing the count of videos wherever plan A is a part. I don't want like that.

Comment: Can you help me to do one more thing. I want to get the videoid of all videos in the subscribed plan as another query. ie, If plan A (user subscribed plan) is part of Plan B, then I should get all videos in Plan A and B.

Comment: For the last requirement, I tried with `select videoid from subscribed_videos where plan_id  IN (SELECT DISTINCT assosiated_plan_id 
         FROM subscription_groups sg
         JOIN subscribed_videos sv ON sv.plan_id = sg.plan_id where  sg.plan_id=1)` and is working fine. Can you please check whether this query is proper or not.

Comment: @Jenz see my updated answer and for the last part you have asked i will update you on this after some time

Comment: @Jenz sorry i was busy whole day you can mail me @dianuj@hotmail.com what ever you need regarding your problem